# Concatenating of two one dimensional array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two one dimensional List say A and B. Each of the list has 2000 elements. I want to merge this two list in python to form tow dimensional array e.g.

```
A=[“Apple”,”Ant”,”Avocado”....]
B=[“Banana”,”Bear”,”Brinjal”,....]
```

Merge list should be 2000 rows in a way that each row will have two columns. As per above example first row will have “Apple” and “Banana”, second row will be “Ant” and “Bear”.

Tried `X = A + B`, however this does not work.

Comment: perhaps `[list(item) for item in zip(A,B)]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is one of the simplest solutions:

```
A = ["Apple", "Ant", "Avocado"]
B = ["Banana", "Bear", "Brinjal"]

result = [[A[i], B[i]] for i in range(len(A))]
print(result)
```

you can use this one liner too:

```
result = list(zip(A, B))
```

If you strictly want `list` of `lists` then try this:

```
result = [list(value) for value in zip(A,B)]
```